# Highlighting selected polygon features without filling colors in QGIS while editing?

Tags: qgis, polygon, editing

When editing in QGIS, how can I highlight the selected polygon features without filling them with colors i.e. just outline the polygon boundary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set selection color transparent and border color red in QGis using python](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174664/set-selection-color-transparent-and-border-color-red-in-qgis-using-python)

Comment: There's no mention of Python/PyQGIS in either the question or self-answer so I don't think this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

If the style of the polygon feature is color filled, just change it to outline color.

Then while in editing mode, the selected polygon will become outline instead of the filled color.