# How to flash selected feature using pyqgis?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, animation, gui

In ArcGIS, when one clicks a feature with the `identify` tool, it will flash/flicker, which makes the feature really easy to see for a moment. Reportedly, there is also a `flash` method in its [ArcObject API](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-java/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/controls/ARFeature.html#flash()).

Is there a way to flash a set of selected feature to the same effect with PyQGIS (2.x or 3.0)?

I searched around, and couldn't find any mention of this or examples

Comment: You could have a look at the [QgsHighlight Class](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsHighlight.html). One of the solutions for [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174664/set-selection-color-transparent-and-border-color-red-in-qgis-using-python) uses it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can build a `flashFeatures` method in this way (give it a try in the QGIS Python Console):

```
from qgis.gui import QgsHighlight
from PyQt4.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt4.QtGui import QColor

timer = QTimer( iface.mapCanvas() )
lstHighlights = []

def flashFeatures( featureIds ):
    global lstHighlights
    for f in iface.activeLayer().getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids(featureIds) ):
        h = QgsHighlight( iface.mapCanvas(), f.geometry(), iface.activeLayer() ) 
        h.setColor( QColor( 255,0,0,255 ) )
        h.setWidth( 5 )
        h.setFillColor( QColor( 255,0,0,100 ) )
        lstHighlights.append( h )
    timer.start( 500 ) # Milliseconds before finishing the flash

def finishFlash():
    timer.stop()
    global lstHighlights
    lstHighlights = []

timer.timeout.connect( finishFlash )
```

Call `flashFeatures` method passing it selected features Ids (activate first your layer in the Layers panel):

```
flashFeatures( iface.activeLayer().selectedFeaturesIds() )
```

If you want to flash features each time they are selected, you could use:

```
iface.activeLayer().selectionChanged.connect( flashFeatures )
```

[image]

Comment: +1, I wonder if it will be nice to have the features flash x number of times consecutively but this is certainly great :)

Answer (score 12):

In 3.0 you can use QGIS's built in [flashFeatureIds](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/gui/Map/QgsMapCanvas.html?highlight=flashfeatureids#qgis.gui.QgsMapCanvas.flashFeatureIds) method on MapCanvas objects

```
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
layer = iface.activeLayer()
my_features_ids = [42, 43, 45]
canvas.flashFeatureIds(layer, my_features_ids)
```

This method also lets you modify the style of the flashing

Comment: +1 Good to know. It's small typo, but in the last line should be 'my_featureS_ids'.

Comment: Good point! Fixed